# MongoDB convert a JSON-String to actual Objects of array "[{obj1},{obj2}]"

Tags: mongodb

I have imported a dataset which contains several documents and each document contain a genres attribure, Its value is **string - A json string** like `"[{'field1':'value1'}, {'field2':'value2'}]"`, please notice the **quote** I want this to be array of objects

```
{
  "genres": "[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751,'name': 'Family'}]"
}
```

Above string values to be converted in following way

```
{
    "title": "Toy story collection",
    "genres": [
        {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, 
        {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, 
        {'id': 10751,'name': 'Family'}
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Shrek",
    "genres": [
        {'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'} 
    ]
},
{
    "title": "Full House",
    "genres": [
        {'id': 10751,'name': 'Family'}
    ]
}
```

This will enable me to search records as follows

```
db.moviesCollection.find({"genres.name":"Animation"})
```

A solution i can think of is load each document one by one though php or javascript and start converting it.

Is there a way? **I can update documentes directly through mongodb itself** without using any programming lanaguge.

Another answer mention something like following but did not mention if they are using any language.

```
db.movies_metadata.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function (el){el.genres=JSON.parse(el.genres);db.movies_metadata.save(el)});
```

If I run above directly on console, I see following error.

> uncaught exception: TypeError: db.movies_metadata.find(...).snapshot
> is not a function : @(shell):1:1

**Updated Answer:**
After getting a great answer here is my final update query, I am using **merge** instead of **replace** as I want to preserve the rest of the attributes

```
db.movies_metadata.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "genres": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(genres) { genres = genres.replace(/'/g, '\"'); return JSON.parse(genres) }",
          "args": [
            "$genres"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "movies_metadata",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: the problem is how to convert the string that contains the json, to real json object? I am not sure that i understand, if this is what you need maybe you need `JSON.parse(your_json_string)` if you use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the value you provided is not a valid `JSON`, it will be something like this:

```
{
    "genres": "[{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"Animation\"},{\"id\":35,\"name\":\"Comedy\"},{\"id\":10751,\"name\":\"Family\"}]"
}
```

Now, there is a way to parse this JSON, within MongoDB itself, using the `$function` stage, and write to a collection using `$merge`, provided you have mongodb version 4.4 or above, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "genres": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(genres) { return JSON.parse(genres) }",
          "args": [
            "$genres"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collectionName",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

See, it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i5102-cAgPy).

This query will work with your existing data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "genres": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(genres) { genres = genres.replace(/'/g, '\"'); return JSON.parse(genres) }",
          "args": [
            "$genres"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collectionName",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U5S7eJfyrml).

Comment: I am afraid thats how data is availble, instead of backslash with double quote, its available as single quote. can we do something in between to replace single quote with that? (some chain, mapping)

Comment: It works as per expectations but it is also removing rest of the attributes

Comment: Use `$addFields` instead of `$project`